# Why is setting the language using the locale not working in a Kotlin-based Android application?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have developed an application that supports multiple languages. During development, when I run the app directly from Android Studio by connecting a USB cable to my device, it functions as expected, and language changes work flawlessly. However, when I generate a signed package for distribution on the Google Play Store, the language setting functionality appears to be malfunctioning. Below is the relevant code snippet for reference:

```
class LanguageManager(private val context: Context) {

    fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String) {
        val locale = Locale(languageCode)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val resources: Resources = context.resources
        val configuration: Configuration = resources.configuration
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

Here it how its called from fragment :

```
 languageManager = LanguageManager(requireContext())
        languageManager.setAppLanguage(language)
```

I would appreciate guidance or assistance in resolving this issue so that the language settings work correctly when the app is downloaded and installed from the Play Store.

Comment: When you say "appears to be malfunctioning", what *exactly* is wrong? Does it fail to set the language, fail to read it correctly, read correctly but show the wrong strings.... you need to debug this so we can help.

Comment: @Jorn It fail to set the language.

Comment: Okay, good start. Now, why does it fail? Any errors in the log? Stack traces?

Comment: No errors. It works fine when i use the app directly from android studio via USB cable.  It works fin set the language etc. But when i generate signed bundle and upload it to google play testing. and i try it then its not setting language.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the locale in the Resources or Context object is not going to change the language in the UI, only the views that are inflated with that updated Context in the future.

To make a per-app locale setting, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#api-implementation

```
val appLocale: LocaleListCompat = LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags("xx-YY")
// Call this on the main thread as it may require Activity.restart()
AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale)
```